# How to enable logs on the PC for web based applications

Tags: oracle-adf

I access an ADF based application through the Web. The application suddenly goes blank and nothing is written in the server logs. For applications using jnlp or java applet we can enable java trace to find what exactly happened when the request was sent to the server. Is there any way we can get similar trace for this web based application?

Regards,
Sameer

Answer (score 0):

ADF generates plenty of logging, but if you get an error and you can't see it in the logs - that developer's fault - bad code that swallows the errors.

Comment: Hi Florin, There is no error per say on the UI, the screen just goes blank. Server logs can capture events that happen with code on the server. How can they capture any issues related to lack of access from client? Do we have ADF client logs?

Comment: This may indeed happen because of a javascript error. Check the browser console (F12 for Chrome) to see if you can't identify custom javascript errors.

Comment: Hi Florin, I logged into the ADF application and disconnected the network, once i reconnected, the page went blank. I then pressed F12 to find this exception "Home:82 Uncaught ReferenceError: panelSplitterPositionChanged is not defined
    at AdfBootstrap._onLoad (Home:82)"  In my case this is a network issue and nothing to do with the application. From this error we cannot relate the issue to the network error. Any thoughts please